# Android activity doesn't get started from popup menu

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to open a new activity, `Make_a_contact`, from my popup menu. The problem I'm sure is related just to the code below, because when I uncomment the code below - `Toast.makeText` etc...(and remove the code I want fixed) it works fine.

Thanks for any help!

```
public void Show_Settings(View v) {
//this is the settings button, whose onclick is identified in menu_thisisatest.xml
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_thisisatest, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Make_a_contact.class);
        return true;
//            @Override
//            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),item.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            return true;
//        }
    });
    popup.show();
}
```

Comment: return inside class body? interesting... which version of java it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start your new Activity after generating your intent. Try calling

```
startActivity(intent);
```

And, of course, you need to include that code in the `onMenuItemClick()` method, that is currently commented out in your code, i.e.

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Make_a_contact.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, although you're most likely right just want to get it working before marking correct. Will have to look at it tomorrow. Had a few errors with brackets etc (new to Android!) and now I get Error:(96, 37) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous OnMenuItemClickListener>,Class<Make_a_contact>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri,Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length) etc etc..anyway, will sort it out tomorrow, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the comment to @Benjamin Scharbau's answer, when you create `intent` with `new Intent(this, Make_a_contact.class)`, `this` is a reference to the anonymous instance of `PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener` class which isn't inherited from `Context` (this is the reason for the error). You should use a context in the `Intent`'s constructor, so use the reference to the calling (foreground) `Activity`, e.g.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ClassNameOfCallingActivity.this, Make_a_contact.class)
```

and pass the `intent` to the `startActivity()` method.

Comment: Onik, thanks for that useful tip. Android is gradually making sense to me. Not sure what all the technical stuff above means but I think @override (which I read an article about) in my code insures it's not drawing its values or whatever from the superclass, Context, which is why I have to give more specification than just 'this'. Cheers, would have taken me a while to get Benjamin's code working without it.